# JPA: 2 databases: one "update", the other "create"

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I want to use **two database schemas**: **one with static data** (which cannot be changed), the **other with dynamic data** (which will change constantly during the execution of the Spring application).

In `application.properties` I have prescribed the following:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/XXXXXX
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root

spring.second-datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/YYYYYY
spring.second-datasource.username=root
spring.second-datasource.password=root
```

But what should I do now with the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` parameter?

For **one** scheme I want to install:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

And for the **other** (where the data is always static):

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

or

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an issue that you need two different datasources. You should define them as 2 different beans and autowire them seperately. For clarity it's advisable to also use 2 different properties files.

You can create a Configuration class and use specific properties file to populate fields like so:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:db.properties")
public class Config {

  @Value("${db.driverClassName}")
String driverClassName;

  @Value("${db.url}")
String url;

  @Value("${db.username}")
String username;

  @Value("${db.password}")
String password;


  @Bean("datasourceId")
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    var dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
    dataSource.setUrl(url);
    dataSource.setUsername(username);
    dataSource.setPassword(password);
    return dataSource;
  }



  @Bean
  public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(
      { "com.foo.bar" });
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

    return sessionFactory;
  }

  private final Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    hibernateProperties.setProperty(
      "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");    
    return hibernateProperties;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Even if I separate the two database schemas in this way, how do I indicate that one data source needs to be recreated, and the other does not need to?

Comment: updated my answer to show how you could define a session factory for hibernate that uses said datasource and properties in which you can define wanted population method.